# how to remove an event handler in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to display a qTip when I click on the `div`. But,that qTip is displayed when the mouse enters the `div`.

I did not add any event except `click`.

On the first time the mouse enters it is not working, but the mouse over will activate after I click the `div` the first time.

After the first click on the `div`, if the mouse enters into the div that qTip is displayed, but I don't want to display the qTip while the mouse enters the div.

My code is:

```
.on('click', '.selectionOptions', function(){
            $(this).qtip({
                id: 'selection_delete',
                style: {
                   classes: 'ui-component-config selectionOpt',
                   tip:false
                    },
                content:{
                        text:'HAI'
                    },
                show: {
                    event:'click'
                    }   
                },
                hide: {
                    when:'unfocus'
                }
            )};
        )};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$( "#foo" ).unbind();
```

or

```
$( ".selectionOptions" ).click(function() {
    $( "body" )
    .off( "click", $(this), flash )
    .find( "#theone" )
      .text( "Does nothing..." );
    });
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

It should be the following:

`$(".element").off();`